# selecting summing multiple columns in R programming

Tags: r, dplyr

What I am looking for is count for no of records in columns for multiple conditions

so some select query like
 select period, country, count(no of rows for sex=Male), count(no of rows for sex=female),count(no of rows for sex=female and age>30)
group by period,country

I am currently using dplyr package and I am able to get count for 1 column at a time how to get for multiple coulms

DATA
SR NO Name AGE GENDER LOCATION working hours REGION
1     XYZ1   32  M      ABC      23          A
2     XYZ2   45  M      ABC2     12          A
3     XYZ3   49  F      ABC3     15          B

Select region,locality count(name) for age>35, sum(working hours) for gender=M
group by region,locality

output
region locality N   N2
A      ABC      0   23
A      ABC2     1   12 
B      ABC3     1   0

This is what I am looking for sum within each column each having diffrent criteria

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the number of rows, you can use a solution from dplyr using summarize:

```html
head(iris)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa


iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length>5.5 & Sepal.Width>1.5 & Species=="setosa") %>% summarize(n=n())

And you'll get the total number of rows that meets that condition:

  n
1 3
```

You can use & (AND) or | (OR) statements to group multiple columns together.

Comment: Yes it is okay but I want to do multiple selections in the same query . can you explain how to summarize multiple columns in the same selection.

Comment: The dplyr example above is doing multiple selections at once. If you want something different, can you edit your question and create a dummy dataframe and then manually edit it to show what you want your result to be?

Comment: I have edited my question and added data can someone now answer this

Comment: you need to fix the formatting of your question, I can't understand the example

Answer (score 0):

```
q1 <- tbl(con, "bank") %>%
  group_by(month_idx, year, month) %>%
  summarise(
    subscribe = sum(ifelse(term_deposit == "yes", 1, 0)),
    total = n())
show_query(q1)
```

Comment: It's fine to answer your own questions but please make them reproducible so that the community as a whole benefits. All you need to add is a sample of data and output which confirms the code. Have a look at: [mre], [answer]